# Formatting y-scale ticks in ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to define what is written on the ticks of the y-axis in a ggplot plot. 
The particular problem is that I want the y-axis to show one decimal point. Instead of `25` it should read `25.0`. I can of course hard-code it in by hand; but this is extremely tedious. (The code below does what it is supposed to do)

```
library(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(c(0:100),c(0:100)) colnames(DF)=c("x","y")

pl <- ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + 

        scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,25.0,50.0,75.0,100.0),
                           labels = c("0","25.0","50.0","75.0","100.0"))
```

Is there a way to format the x and y axis without having to type the exact labels in myself?

Instead of `labels = c("0","25.0","50.0","75.0","100.0")` there should be a command that whatever the ticks on the y-axis, the labeling should be done with one digit after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
pl <- ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, nsmall = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try format:

```
pl <- ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + 

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,25.0,50.0,75.0,100.0),
                     labels = format(c("0","25","50","75","100"),nsmall=1))
```